# Remove text from B2C custom policy sign up flow

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, aad-b2c

In the sign up page, when the existing user tries to sign up, it gives an error, this user already exists. But it shows the text, ''confirmed email address'' , how can we remove the text? [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you create custom policy you should be able to define this message in Localization part of the policy.

Example of this file is here:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/main/Display%20Controls%20Starterpack/LocalAccounts/TrustFrameworkLocalization.xml

```
  <!-- Generic errors -->
  <LocalizedString ElementType="ErrorMessage" StringId="ServiceThrottled">There are too many requests at this moment. Please wait for some time and try again.</LocalizedString>
  <LocalizedString ElementType="ErrorMessage" StringId="UserMessageIfClaimNotVerified">Claim not verified: {0}</LocalizedString>
  <LocalizedString ElementType="ErrorMessage" StringId="UserMessageIfClaimsPrincipalAlreadyExists">A user with the specified ID already exists. Please choose a different one.</LocalizedString>
  <LocalizedString ElementType="ErrorMessage" StringId="UserMessageIfIncorrectPattern">Incorrect pattern for: {0}</LocalizedString>
  <LocalizedString ElementType="ErrorMessage" StringId="UserMessageIfInvalidInput">{0} has invalid input.</LocalizedString>
  <LocalizedString ElementType="ErrorMessage" StringId="UserMessageIfMissingRequiredElement">Missing required element: {0}</LocalizedString>
  <LocalizedString ElementType="ErrorMessage" StringId="UserMessageIfValidationError">Error in validation by: {0}</LocalizedString>
```